# Error when trying to install pip on openSUSE

Tags: python, pip, rpm, opensuse

I'm trying to deploy `pip` on my production server, but have an illogical error, where it tries to install without success a composent which is already installed.

```
~> sudo zypper in python-pip
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: python-pip-1.0.2-3.1.2.noarch requires python = 2.7, but this requirement cannot be provided
  uninstallable providers: python-2.7.2-7.10.1.i586[Updates-for-openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4]
                   python-2.7.2-7.17.1.i586[Updates-for-openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4]
                   python-2.7.2-7.10.1.x86_64[Updates-for-openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4]
                   python-2.7.2-7.17.1.x86_64[Updates-for-openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4]
                   python-2.7.2-7.1.3.x86_64[openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4]
                   python-2.7.2-7.1.3.i586[repo-oss]
                   python-2.7.2-7.1.3.x86_64[repo-oss]
 Solution 1: deinstallation of patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts 12.1-25.21.1.x86_64
 Solution 2: do not install python-pip-1.0.2-3.1.2.noarch
 Solution 3: do not install python-pip-1.0.2-3.1.2.noarch
 Solution 4: break python-pip-1.0.2-3.1.2.noarch by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/3/4/c] (c): c
```

This is unbelievable because `python-2.7.2-7.17.1` is installed for the good platform (x86_64)

```
~> sudo zypper if python-base
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...


Information for package python-base:

Repository: Updates for openSUSE 12.1 12.1-1.4
Name: python-base
Version: 2.7.2-7.17.1
Arch: x86_64
Vendor: openSUSE
Installed: Yes
Status: up-to-date
Installed Size: 20.8 MiB
Summary: Python Interpreter base package
Description:
Python is an interpreted, object-oriented programming language, and is
often compared to Tcl, Perl, Scheme, or Java.  You can find an overview
of Python in the documentation and tutorials included in the python-doc
(HTML) or python-doc-pdf (PDF) packages.

This package contains all of stand-alone Python files, minus binary
modules that would pull in extra dependencies.
```

Uninstalling `patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts 12.1-25.21.1.x86_64` mutes the problem; but is there a clean way to solve that problem?

Comment: I think there needs to be more data collected and troubleshooting done. The first thing you need to rule out is whether or not this occurs on a clean image. Once you've determined whether it occurs on a clean machine I'd be interested in seeing if you use a different repo between the two boxes. Please collect more information for us to go on, currently this isn't enough data.

Comment: Strange. I'm having the same problem with OpenSuse 13.2(amd64) installed from the netInstall image.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the issue was that I was using a wrong zypper repository (openSuse instead of SLE SP3).

I uninstalled the faulty pip, removed the wrong repository, added the correct respository and finally re-installed pip again. Then it worked.