# Not able to install python-pip on SUSE

Tags: python, pip, suse

I have a sandbox environment of SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 for VMware  (x86_64), and trying to install python-pip on it through terminal using this command:

```
sudo zypper in python-pip
```

I am getting this message: `Package 'python-pip' not found`.

I tried to install pip using `python get-pip.py` after downloading `get-pip.py`
It gives me this:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
No distributions at all found for pip
```

Comment: And Check Out Here Same Problem  :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860085/error-when-trying-to-install-pip-on-opensuse][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860085/error-when-trying-to-install-pip-on-opensuse

Answer (score 4):

Very old issue. I recently needed to install SLE12sp5 on Power and hit similar challenge with pip. This was a fully licensed SLES edition, so I had access to all available SUSE zypper repos.

The default install on sp5 includes (python) Python 2.7.18 and (python3) Python 3.4.10. I could not find a suitable pip package to install for either.

Poking around I found python itself comes with a module to bootstrap pip. This can be invoked with:

python -m ensurepip

python3 -m ensurepip

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html

On the new Power SLE12sp5 system, the python3 version was successful, however this did not help me as I needed to use Ansible which requires versions greater then 3.4.   The python v2 did not work as it seems like something is out of sync with 'setuptools'.

I was ultimately able to solve the Ansible & pip requirement on my system with SUSE's official install of python 3.6 which happens to include pip as well.

And with that I need to use the following in my inventory:
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.6

but that's a small price to pay for getting out of this dependency trap.

Comment: `python3 -m ensurepip` seems to be working, thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Please Follow instructions from below link for OpenSUSE

[python-pip from Cloud:Tools project](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=Cloud%3ATools&package=python-pip)

---

#### Mirroring instructions for quick goto:

For SLE 12 SP4 run the following as root:

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Cloud:Tools/SLE_12_SP4/Cloud:Tools.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install python-pip
```

For SLE 12 SP3 run the following as root:

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Cloud:Tools/SLE_12_SP3/Cloud:Tools.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install python-pip
```

For SLE 12 run the following as root:

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Cloud:Tools/SLE_12/Cloud:Tools.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install python-pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Example for SLES12 SP3:

```
touch  /etc/zypp/repos.d/devel_languages_python.repo
cat < EOF > /etc/zypp/repos.d/devel_languages_python.repo
[devel_languages_python]
name=Python Modules (SLE_12_SP3)
type=rpm-md
baseurl=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python/SLE_12_SP3/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python/SLE_12_SP3/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled=1
EOF
zypper ref
# choose trust when asked for the signing key
zypper in -y python-pip
```

Comment: Didn't really work: 
Retrieving repository 'Python Modules (SLE_12_SP3)' metadata ----------------[\]
File '/repodata/repomd.xml' not found on medium 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python/SLE_12_SP3/'

Comment: If you check the link at download.opensuse.org, the one I put there is no longer available. So the same goes, but you might try to find the one that is currently active, for example this one: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/infrastructure/SLE_12_SP3/src/

Comment: Maybe this will work: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python:/backports/SLE_12_SP3/repodata/